# Unable to start my first react native app on ubuntu, error Failed to launch emulator

Tags: ubuntu, bash, android

Can anyone help plz as i've searched everywhere for solution but failed.

Am getting this error message: 
**error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.**

but when i enter the command `emulator -list-avds` am able to see my emulator **Pixel_2_API_25**
and the emulator also loads in the **android studio**.

I declared all the environment variables below in both the **~/.profile** file and **~/.bashrc** file

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

but still am getting the error, and also this error: **error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up**

Answer (score 0):

i finally fix the error by doing this:

**cd $HOME**

**sudo chmod 777 -R Android**

And then react-native was able to access my emulator

The problem was caused by just file permission problem :)